# ngFor not refreshing in Angular2 and keeps on adding elements

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ngfor

I have a variable `var` as a drop down in my html.
As my variable changes, A list is displayed for that particular value of `var`.
Like :

```
<ul *ngFor="let value in someArrayDependentOnvarInTheAboveDropdown">
    <li> {{value}} </li>
</ul>
```

Again as I change `var` in the dropdown, the array `someArrayDependentOnvarInTheAboveDropdown` is also changed in the function. But the previous `li` values are also shown in the html. 
Like:

```
<li> Value1 from var1 </li>
<li> Value1 from var1 </li>
<li> Value1 from var2 </li>
<li> Value1 from var3 </li>
<li> Value1 from var3 </li>
....
```

Please help in resolving this. Thanks in advance.

This is the exact code snippet

```
changePlSelection(productLine) {
        console.log(productLine.product_line_name); 
        this.selectedProductLine = productLine;

        var position = 0;
        for(var i=0; i < this.productLinesList.length; ++i) {
            if(productLine.product_line_id == this.productLinesList[i].product_line_id) {
                position = i;
                break;
            }
        }

        this.selectedProductApplicationsList = this.productApplicationsList[position];
}
```

And the html code is :

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let productLine of productLinesList"> 
        {{productLine.product_line_name}}
        <input type="radio" 
               name="radiogroup" 
               [value]="productLine.product_line_id" 
               (change)="changePlSelection(productLine)">
    </li>
</ul>


<ul>
    <li id="list-of-pa" *ngFor="let productApplication of selectedProductApplicationsList"> 
    {{productApplication.product_application_name}}    
    <input type="radio" 
           name="radiogroup2" 
           [value]="productApplication.product_application_id" 
           (change)="changePaSelection(productApplication)">
     </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Try to empty the variable first by setting `var.length = 0` and then updating the value of variable.

Comment: are you making your variable empty each time calling that function? like let var = '';

Comment: You should work on immutable object to render a new array on DOM. Paste your code of changing array so that I can help better.

Comment: try using `ngOnChanges`

Comment: Please past your dropdown change function. Unless we can't resolve your problem.